# Deploy source to org fails with "No authorization information found"

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, salesforcedx-cli, vs-code, sfdx-error

I'm just getting started with developing in VS Code and have been following the steps [here](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/quick-start-lightning-web-components/create-a-hello-world-lightning-web-component).

I was able to authorise my org with the default alias according to the steps [here](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/quick-start-lightning-web-components/create-a-hello-world-lightning-web-component):

[image]

The authorised org also shows up in my `auth:list`:

[image]

And running `sfdx force:org:display --targetusername vscodeOrg`, confirms the org's `Connected Status: Connected`.

But when I try to deploy the component as per step 2 [here](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/quick-start-lightning-web-components/create-a-hello-world-lightning-web-component) with **SFDX: Deploy Source to Org**, I get the error message `No authorization information found for vscodeOrg`:

[image]

**Would anyone know what's going on here?** I can't find much information about this error and I'm worried I've broken something, so any help would be much appreciated.

---

EDIT: Updating the CLI with `sfdx update` seemed to resolve the issue for me.

Comment: As an aside, if you are just starting out with VSCode and sfdx, consider using scratch orgs and git for your development and version control.

Comment: I also faced the same issue. Restarting the VS Code worked for me.

Answer (score 15):

I had the same issue. I restarted Vscode and after that it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I am facing this kind of error a lot recently.
For me none of these `update sfdx` or restarting VScode works.
In my case, when I execute `SFDX: Authorize an Org` and then execute `sfdx force:org:list`, there is connected org but no default org.

if you are facing same problem, execute `sfdx force:config:set defaultusername=xxx@abc.com`, which works for me.

Answer (score 0):

sfdx update took care of this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my situation, authorizing the org once again or switching the default org to a different one and switching back and then deploying the component worked

Answer (score -2):

1. If there is an update in sfdx kindly update it to the latest version
2. Restart your VS Code
3. Then type in force:org:display -a which would display the org details such as the connection status
4. If disconnected then reconnect it again by using SFDX:Authorize and Org

Answer (score -2):

In my case what helped was to run the following command from the VScode's terminal:

```
sfdx force:org:list --all
```

Answer (score -2):

I ran into the same issue. What helped for me was configuring the path to JAVA in VSCode. https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode/en/vscode-desktop/java-setup