# Some LWC files can not be retrieved

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx

I am not able to retrieve some LWC files from the org.
In setting → Lightning Component, it is existed on org
[image]
but if I specifically tried to retrieve the file, it is getting an error:

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m LightningComponentBundle:assetHierarchy
Preparing retrieve request... done
=== Retrieved Source

No results found
=== Retrieved Source Warnings

 FILE NAME              PROBLEM                                                                          
 ────────────────────── ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── 
 unpackaged/package.xml Entity of type 'LightningComponentBundle' named 'assetHierarchy' cannot be found
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: `sfdx force:mdapi:retrieve -s -r ./mdapipkg` command also does not work.

Comment: The component in question isn't part of a managed package, is it?

Comment: I am not sure my sfdx environment is not stable after installed local-lwc-server.
I uninstalled it, removed all connected orgs from sfdx command, and then it finally works. Thank you for comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I got this weird problem, when I hit `sfdx force:org:list`, there is no authorized org as a result. (of course I did "Authorize an Org" command many times)
So I uninstalled / reinstalled sfdx and hit `sfdx auth:logout --all`, finally it works as before.

Comment: You mention uninstalling sfdx. I assume you then re-installed it "clean"?

Comment: hi @PhilW, I followed this step. [Uninstall Salesforce CLI or Plug-ins](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_uninstall.htm), is that you meant "clean"?

I am not sure why this kind of error happens many times recently, looks like this guy is also facing a same issue as me.
[https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/388801/deploy-source-to-org-fails-with-no-authorization-information-found]

Comment: By "clean" I meant without then installing other plugins etc. My point is you are using sfdx but the way you phrased things in the answer is that you first uninstalled it then used it to logout. Clearly that would not work. Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/392296/edit) the answer to clarify the exact steps.

Comment: I don't really understand what you said. So what's is the way to uninstall sfdx "clean"? Please provide a step.

Comment: You said you uninstalled sfdx **then** used an sfdx command. Clearly you cannot use an sfdx command with sfdx uninstalled. I assume you uninstalled then reinstalled sfdx but you did not say that and did not explain why uninstalling and reinstalling was of help.

Comment: Got it! Yeah totally. I modified the answer. Sorry for the hassle.

Comment: May I suggest another edit - mention that you had some specific add-on plugins installed that you did not re-install...?

Comment: At this time, actually I didn't do that any. 
Do you think "Salesforce CLI Integration" should be uninstalled?

Comment: You mentioned having local-lwc-server...? Basically trying to figure out why your uninstall/reinstall would solve the issue.

Comment: Right. Of course I wanted to uninstall it but there is no guide of the way to uninstall it. Actually we should reinstall local-lwc-server after un/reinstalling sfdx.